# How to get data from mysql in android fragment class?

Tags: android, json, fragment

I want to get the profile details from mysql db from fragment class. should display to textview. like student name, address, mobile etc.. I used JSON format to send the data from php.

here is my code

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
private View parentView;
// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session;
TextView student_name;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
//URL to get JSON Array
private String url;

//JSON Node Names
private static final String TAG_ARRAY = "student_profile";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "student_name";
JSONArray student_profile = null;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
     parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
     //session.checkLogin();
     session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
     session.checkLogin();
     return parentView;
}   

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    new JSONParse().execute();  
}

private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    private JSONObject json;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        student_name = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.studentname);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        // name
        String emailaddr = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);
        url = "http://XXXXXXX.org/api/profile.php?emailid="+emailaddr;
        // Getting JSON from URL
        json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
             // Getting JSON Array from URL
             student_profile = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY);
             for(int i = 0; i < student_profile.length(); i++){
                 JSONObject c = student_profile.getJSONObject(i);
                 String student_firstname = null;
                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                 String name = c.getString(student_firstname);
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "name="+name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I got the error like this

```
12-24 09:29:44.817: W/System.err(30999): org.json.JSONException: No value for student_profile
```

12-24 09:29:44.818: W/System.err(30999):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
12-24 09:29:44.819: W/System.err(30999):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
12-24 09:29:44.819: W/System.err(30999):    at com.tutorialsface.ResideMenuDemo.ProfileFragment$JSONParse.onPostExecute(ProfileFragment.java:89)

Comment: check ur url on browser. i think php return empty json

Comment: show your json contents

Comment: {"student_firstname":"Iyan","student_lastname":"Hume","student_photo":"","student_address":"dfgsdf","student_mobile":"3333333333","student_father_name":"","student_dob":"","student_mother_mobile":"","student_landphone":"","student_conveyance":"","standard_name":null,"division_name":"B"}

Comment: In this code Im getting the data..

json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

{"student_mother_mobile":"","student_conveyance":"","standard_name":null,"student_dob":"","student_lastname":"Hume","student_firstname":"Iyan","student_photo":"","student_father_name":"","student_address":"dfgsdf","student_landphone":"","division_name":"B","student_mobile":"3333333333"}

Comment: As you can see from looking at that JSON, and as the exception indicates, there is no value for student_profile.  So as Sar said, check for the value before you try to get it, and take appropriate action if it isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

I  think your json has no values for TAG_ARRAY.So its giving JSONException.
You should first check value like :

```
if (json.has(TAG_ARRAY)) {
 student_profile = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY);
}
```

Then it will not produce JSONException.